# iOS control center drag button color

Tags: ios, button, colors

I want to know how the control center drag button get's it's color by the lock screen wallpaper.

I post a picture here to understand what button i mean : [image]

Comment: this button only shows that this sheet will closed in downward direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not getting a color; it's a semi-transparent grey/black like the rest of the icons in Control Center. The background blue is from a mix of [blur and vibrancy effects](http://applidium.com/en/news/mastering_blur_and_vibrancy_with_iOS_8/).